# Using ReactiveMongoTemplate with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing a reactive application using Spring Boot 2.3.0, MongoDB, and Kotlin. Unlikely, I need to develop a custom repository using the `ReactiveMongoTemplate` object. Since all the application uses Kotlin coroutines, I will be very happy if also this repository could use them.

For example, I developed a simple update on a Mongo collection:

```
override suspend fun addQuantityToStockInAPortfolio(
    portfolio: String, 
    stock: String,
    quantity: Long): UpdateResult? {
  return mongo.updateFirst(
      Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").isEqualTo(portfolio)),
      Update().inc("stocks.$stock", quantity),
      MongoPortfolio::class.java
   ).block()
}
```

The only way I found to translate a `Mono<T>` into the return type of a `suspend fun` is to call the `block()` method on it.

Is there a more natural way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. `block()` is not idiomatic and can lead to problems by blocking a thread which is not supposed to be blocked.

You should use one of the await extension functions like `awaitSingle()` which will not block the thread, just suspend instead.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.awaitSingle

// other code

override suspend fun addQuantityToStockInAPortfolio(
    portfolio: String, 
    stock: String,
    quantity: Long): UpdateResult {
  return mongo.updateFirst(
      Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").isEqualTo(portfolio)),
      Update().inc("stocks.$stock", quantity),
      MongoPortfolio::class.java
   ).awaitSingle()
}
```